# SafeBrowsing Lookup API on mobile

Tags: android, api

Can SafeBrowsing Lookup API service be used in Android application?. For example, a part of  android application that checks whether a specific url is harmful or not (this is not the same as using a web browser). Since all the documentations refer to the use of the service in Desktops and PCs. And as this service requires to maintain a local database on the client that got updated every a few minutes, will it be efficient to implement in a mobile app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I could handle it, it is working now. I could implement it using GET method and I am getting results that determine whether a specific URL is a phishing/malware or not. I will post the code here when I have the clean version of it.